# How to PATCH the following parameters using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, patch

How to Patch the following RestAPI, patch should not be MultipartFormData

Here are my parameters, that I need to patch:

```
let parametersText = ["project":["title":"test",
                                 "description":"test",
                                 "priority":false]
```

Here is the Curl:

```
curl -X PATCH "http://localhost:2202/api/project/1" -H "accept: aplication/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "project=%7B%22title%22%3A%22Test%20Title%22%2C%22description%22%3A%22Test%20description%20for%20new%20project%22%2C%22priority%22%3Afalse%7D"
```

Here is how I do my Post request (it works) :

```
let url = serverURL+"/api/project"
let parametersText = ["project":["title":requestName.text!,"description":requestDescription.text!,"priority":emergencySwitch.isOn,"category_id":selectedCategoryID,"location_id":selectedLocationID]]

CustomHTTPHeaderRequest.customRequest().upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    for (key, value) in parametersText {
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
        } catch(let err){
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

},to: url,
  method: .post,
  encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        self.alamofireDidFinishUploading(upload: upload)
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)
    }
})
```

Comment: You want to add parameters along with upload of image?

Comment: What would you like to do?